# Extending inline a generic abstract Template class

Tags: java, generics, inline, abstract

So, this is a follow up question I had from earlier. I have written the following code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

public abstract class IterableList<T> {
    public void perfrom(List<T> ls) {
    Iterator<T> l = ls.iterator();
        while (l.hasNext())
            action(l.next());
    }   
    protected abstract void action(T obj);
}
```

Which is to create a template (sorta like a macro in C) so I can implement the action method and iterate through many things in a list. I'm having problems with the code to do this inline (I think that is the word?), but I can't figure out how to write it using generics. To give you an example of what I am trying to do, I basically want to do the following:

```
new IterableList<String>{
   void action(String s) {
       // do something
   }
}.perform(myListOfStrings);
```

But I'm not really getting any luck, and I'm not given any helpful errors. I am sort of out of my familiarity zone in Java, I haven't programmed in the language for quite a while.

So far the errors I get (in eclipse) are "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" and "void is an invalid type for the variable action". Which aren't really helpful as far as I can understand.

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried?

Comment: You need to provide more information, specifically what isn't working and the specific reason you believe it's not doing what you want.  Otherwise nobody is going to be able to help you.  Based on the little code you've provided it looks OK so far, so the problem is in code you haven't shared.

Comment: I get "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" and "void is an invalid type for the variable action" I'm not really sure. I'm using eclipse. That's the only error information I get. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little wrong.

```
List<String> myListOfStrings = ...// some List

new IterableList<String>() { // missing ()
    public void action(String s) {
        // do something
    }
}.perfrom(myListOfStrings);
```

Note that you cannot reduce the visibility of your methods. `action` is declared as `public` in the parent class, so `action()` in the child class needs to be at least `public`. Also, `perform` is misspelled.

The above would be equivalent to

```
public class AnonymousClass extends IterableList<String> {
    public void action(String s) {
        // do something
    }
}

...
new AnonymousClass().perfrom(myListOfStrings);
```

Comment: You can define an abstract method in a generic fashion and then implement it without generics?

Comment: @SteveP Check this last edit. Hope that explains it.